# Are fputwc and fgetwc significantly faster than fprintf and fscanf? Why is it so?

Tags: c, performance, io, wchar-t

I am working on files using characters of `wcahr_t` type. I would like to make my program faster.

Does it make any sense to substitute `fprintf` with `fputwc` and `fscanf` with `fgetwc` wherever possible?

If so, why?

Comment: Most likely not. But more importantly, do not optimize without profiling! If the program is slow, it is unlikely this is the cause.

Comment: I've already substituted everything with fputwc and fgetwc. Now it is about 10% faster. A huge part of my program is reading/writing character from/to a file. I'd love to learn why is it faster.

Comment: It might be better to use `snprintf/sprintf` followed by `fwrite`.

Comment: @RSahu. If I want to use `wchar_t` than I should use `swprintf`, yes? Why is it faster?

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski, I misunderstood. If you are dealing with just `wchar_t`, you don't need to use `snprintf/sprintf/swprintf`. You can just store the data in an array and write the data out using `fwrite`. I am guessing it will be faster since you will be accessing the disk less number of times. I don't have any data to support my suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some quick profiling using only a single `wchar_t` per call, and there is indeed a noticable difference. First, the code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "wchar.h"

wchar_t text[] = L"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789#$";
const int N = 64;
const int M = 500000;
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    FILE *f1 = fopen("out1", "w");
    FILE *f2 = fopen("out2", "w");

    if (f1 == NULL || f2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to create file.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    clock_t time1 = clock();
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            fprintf(f1, "%c", text[j]);
    time1 = clock() - time1;


    clock_t time2 = clock();
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            fputwc(text[j], f2);
    time2 = clock() - time2;

    printf("fprintf: %d ticks\nfputwc: %d ticks\n", time1, time2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output for gcc:

> fprintf: 5663 ticks
>
> fputwc: 3307 ticks

Output for clang:

> fprintf: 4696 ticks
>
> fputwc: 3338 ticks

---

Writing to stdout or to a memory buffer has the same time difference, so this has nothing to do with how they write or when they flush, etc. It is just the function implementations. Let's take a look at them:

The most obvious difference is that `fprintf` takes a format, which it must parse. So, the minimal job it must do is:

```
while (*fmt) {
    if (*fmt++ == '%') {
        switch (*fmt)
        {
        case 'c': *output = va_arg(args, int); break;
        ...
      }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the code has to do several checks and increments that `fputwc` doesn't, which means extra execution time. <s>The position of `case 'c'` among other cases actually matters, the lower it is, the slower it will be.</s>(see comments) These differences will likely account for most of the extra time.

Specifically in case of `printf("%c", x)`, we have:

- Setting up the initial state - Let's say 5-30 instructions
- Reading the first character and comparing with `'%'` - about 5 instructions
- Reading the second character, switch statement - about 10 instructions.

After this, it does pretty much the same thing as `fputwc`. All these extra instructions per call do add up.

There are some other things which can influence this, such as an extra argument being passed, but a good compiler can optimize that away.

---

All that said, this is a horribly inefficient way to deal with this. You should probably write to a buffer and then call `fwrite` (which I've clocked as similar to `fputwc`) and dump the entire buffer in a single call. One thing to note is that `fwrite(f, sizeof(wchar_t), N, text);` will actually output the 0 bytes as well, ending up with `"a\0b\0c\0"` and so on.

Comment: This is a good answer *except* for the sentence reading "the position of `case 'c'` among other cases actually matters, ...", which is flat-out wrong.  Write a test function with a case statement over a randomly-selected handful of letters, dump out (optimized) assembly, and you will discover that the compiler has generated code which is order-independent, and at worst O(lg n) in the *total* number of cases.

Comment: Yeah, as @zwol says, these days `switch` statements are optimized as lookup tables whenever possible, making them faster than a chain of `if/else if`.

Comment: @zwol Will do. But, depending on which cases you list, compiler can generate either a jump to a calculated address (O(1)), a decision tree (O(log(total_cases)), or an if-else-if chain (O(position_of_case)). The first one is impossible in this case, and the second one is unlikely as the total number of cases is small enough, so that O(log(n)) isn't that much better than O(n)

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo It isn't always possible to make a jump table. There's three ways to do it, see my previous comment.

Comment: @mtijanic Why do you think a jump table is impossible?  The characters involved are: `<SPC>#%'+-.0123456789ACEFGILSXacdefghijlmnopstuxz` for a total numeric range (assuming ASCII) of 90 jump table slots, of which 45 are non-`default` -- that is not nearly sparse enough to make a jump table a poor tradeoff.

Comment: @zwol I'd like to remind you that we are considering wchar_t, not char. Thanks! I can learn a lot from your discussion!

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski A case statement over `wchar_t` *could* be much bigger and sparser than a case statement over `char`.  However, the set of abstract characters that can appear in a `printf` format specifier is the same whether or not you're using the wide version, so *that* case statement should produce exactly the same code except possibly for the initial range check.  (Assuming the encoding of `wchar_t` is ASCII-compatible, which as far as I know it always is.)

Comment: @zwol You are right, I just wrote a switch with all those and it did generate a lookup table. I tried a more sparse version with 10 cases and that was an if-else-if chain. So, yes, my comment doesn't stand, but those chains do happen fairly often. I'll note this in the answer.